# working with two combo boxes

Tags: c#

Im using c# .net windows form application. I have two comboboxes A and B .I have pouplated A with some values. Now if i select any one value from A, I should be able to populate B with all the items of A except the selected item .

Comment: yes, you should be able doing that. Where is the question ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want this :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count;i++)
    {
        if ((comboBox1.SelectedIndex)!=i)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(comboBox2.Items[i]);
        }
    }
```

you have to clear comboBox2 before adding new items

Answer (score 1):

in the selected item changed event of A, add code which clears B, then loops round each item in A's Item collection and adds it to B as long as the index of the current item is different from the index of the SelectedItem in A.

Something like (pseudo code, not tested)

```
b.Items.Clear;
for(int i=0; i<A.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (i!=A.SelectedItemIndex)
    {
    b.Items.Add(A.Items[i]);
    } 
}
```

or

```
B.Items.Clear;
foreach(object o in A.Items)
{
     b.Items.Add(o);
}
b.Items.Remove(A.SelectedItem);
```

should do it as well.

Answer (score 1):

here is simple example of how you could go about this:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AComboBox.Items.Add("1");
            AComboBox.Items.Add("2");
            AComboBox.Items.Add("3");
            AComboBox.Items.Add("4");
            AComboBox.Items.Add("5");
            AComboBox.Items.Add("6");
        }

        private void AComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BComboBox.Items.Clear();

            //* One way.
            foreach (object obj in AComboBox.Items.Cast<object>().Where(obj => !obj.Equals(AComboBox.Text)))
            {
                BComboBox.Items.Add(obj);
            }

            //* Another way (if possible duplicates in A).
            for (int i = 0; i < AComboBox.Items.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (i != AComboBox.SelectedIndex)
                    BComboBox.Items.Add(AComboBox.Items[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

well since you say both have same values. on the selected event of first one.  get the selected item and remove it from the second combo. simple